R How to Split MULTISTRING sf objects Based on Points
I have grouped connected lines and now would like to split these lines into smaller groups based on points. I have found a couple of examples of how to do this with LINESTRING geometries but not with MULTILINESTRING geometries. See here and here. Using either of these methods I get an sf object containing LINESTRING's. Of course I can aggregate these back to a MULTILINESTRING based on my group column but this only serves to get me back to where I started. I need all the lines on 1 side of the intersecting point group into a MULTILINESTRING and all the other lines on the other side group into a separate MULTILINESTRING and with both sides having a different group #. To make things more difficult my splitting point exist on an existing line vertex. I am looking to do this splitting in the most efficient way possible as my real world dataset is very large. See my sample dataset below.
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
        testArea<-structure(list(group = 3, geom = structure(list(structure(list(
    structure(c(6502476.72250405, 6502454.02996413, 1962622.20532215, 
    1962613.17515647), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502476.72250405, 
    6502453.90463631, 1962622.20532215, 1962632.57964523), dim = c(2L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502366.41465381, 6502371.44253089, 6502473.30682847, 
    6502476.72250405, 1962490.68032272, 1962495.74363281, 1962498.12158081, 
    1962622.20532215), dim = c(4L, 2L)), structure(c(6502228.73645148, 
    6502211.24928172, 1962628.79028273, 1962643.49694623), dim = c(2L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502213.34114106, 6502223.08324756, 1962491.00643755, 
    1962467.08522557), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502228.73645148, 
    6502250.32728755, 6502307.72317013, 6502325.46394831, 1962628.79028273, 
    1962625.21515864, 1962624.4385854, 1962633.67150655), dim = c(4L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502671.5715238, 6502661.95999447, 1962487.84240189, 
    1962462.80997165), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502476.72250405, 
    6502494.79891147, 6502552.95102614, 6502581.00116688, 1962622.20532215, 
    1962617.1669464, 1962616.94680248, 1962626.03963207), dim = c(4L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502228.73645148, 6502210.75486013, 1962628.79028273, 
    1962623.37789197), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502366.41465381, 
    6502376.15413564, 6502474.69757372, 6502493.52365156, 6502542.63214913, 
    6502548.52485389, 1962490.68032272, 1962480.89097223, 1962483.04615164, 
    1962483.45789623, 1962483.56846032, 1962488.53531389), dim = c(6L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502366.41465381, 6502367.14956047, 6502405.43065189, 
    1962490.68032272, 1962469.13115323, 1962446.99602689), dim = 3:2), 
    structure(c(6502366.41465381, 6502306.02074572, 1962490.68032272, 
    1962490.85880005), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502306.02074572, 
    6502331.86321372, 1962490.85880005, 1962451.68335348), dim = c(2L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502548.52485389, 6502671.5715238, 1962488.53531389, 
    1962487.84240189), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502476.72250405, 
    6502493.10337681, 6502550.52878688, 6502569.00578405, 1962622.20532215, 
    1962611.71616989, 1962610.93959664, 1962603.28344397), dim = c(4L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502213.34114106, 6502180.82119296, 1962491.00643755, 
    1962465.7459894), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502228.73645148, 
    6502245.1176523, 6502303.41609214, 6502326.35075755, 1962628.79028273, 
    1962618.30080239, 1962617.95959572, 1962614.20074497), dim = c(4L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502366.41465381, 6502361.39957197, 6502228.35587481, 
    6502228.73645148, 1962490.68032272, 1962495.69540456, 1962496.08812031, 
    1962628.79028273), dim = c(4L, 2L)), structure(c(6502548.52485389, 
    6502569.88406314, 1962488.53531389, 1962462.09999931), dim = c(2L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502366.41465381, 6502376.00387347, 6502452.04538806, 
    1962490.68032272, 1962471.47498056, 1962457.93334098), dim = 3:2), 
    structure(c(6502306.02074572, 6502294.69202822, 1962490.85880005, 
    1962453.50651257), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502306.02074572, 
    6502213.34114106, 1962490.85880005, 1962491.00643755), dim = c(2L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502671.5715238, 6502693.53867146, 1962487.84240189, 
    1962463.86377531), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502548.52485389, 
    6502538.80833788, 1962488.53531389, 1962464.75189689), dim = c(2L, 
    2L)), structure(c(6502693.53867146, 6502693.05278005, 1962463.86377531, 
    1962448.23880656), dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(6502507.63714039, 
    6502497.52331547, 6502366.41465381, 1962494.67375307, 1962493.54777107, 
    1962490.68032272), dim = 3:2), structure(c(6502507.63714039, 
    6502517.90418021, 6502555.63835672, 6502736.0713948, 6502735.87224822, 
    6502735.84239264, 1962494.67375307, 1962493.70754765, 1962493.49527773, 
    1962492.47887556, 1962559.16378155, 1962569.20477198), dim = c(6L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "MULTILINESTRING", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_MULTILINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 6502180.82119296, 
ymin = 1962446.99602689, xmax = 6502736.0713948, ymax = 1962643.49694623
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_III_FIPS_0403_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",6561666.666666666],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",1640416.666666667],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-120.5],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",37.06666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",38.43333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",36.5],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NAD83 / California zone 3 (ftUS)\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",6269]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]],\n    CONVERSION[\"unnamed\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",36.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",-120.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",37.0666666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",38.4333333333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",6561666.66666667,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",1640416.66666667,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9003]]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9003]]]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), sf_column = "geom", agr = structure(c(group = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
    
split_point<-structure(list(PhasingCode = 4L, geom = structure(list(structure(c(6502366.41465381, 
1962490.68032272), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 6502366.41465381, 
ymin = 1962490.68032272, xmax = 6502366.41465381, ymax = 1962490.68032272
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "PROJCS[\"NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_III_FIPS_0403_Feet\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_North_American_1983\",DATUM[\"D_North_American_1983\",SPHEROID[\"GRS_1980\",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION[\"Lambert_Conformal_Conic\"],PARAMETER[\"False_Easting\",6561666.666666666],PARAMETER[\"False_Northing\",1640416.666666667],PARAMETER[\"Central_Meridian\",-120.5],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_1\",37.06666666666667],PARAMETER[\"Standard_Parallel_2\",38.43333333333333],PARAMETER[\"Latitude_Of_Origin\",36.5],UNIT[\"Foot_US\",0.3048006096012192]]", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NAD83 / California zone 3 (ftUS)\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",6269]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]],\n    CONVERSION[\"unnamed\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",36.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",-120.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",37.0666666666667,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",38.4333333333333,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",6561666.66666667,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",1640416.66666667,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9003]]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"US survey foot\",0.304800609601219,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9003]]]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 23L, class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geom", agr = structure(c(PhasingCode = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))

You can see a plot of the linework below. The central point should split the MULTILINESTRING into several smaller MULTILINSTRINGs. Lastly, I should note my real-world dataset consist of several MULTILINESTRING's in one sf object.
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = testArea, color = "red") + geom_sf(data = split_point, color = "blue")


I too have the same issue as I want to join roads together but split them at intersections with other roads. The roads have to be multiline for when they split into two divided roads or at roundabouts etc. I tried "split with line", SAGA's "split lines at points".
I am now trying a different approach by starting from singlepart lines and merging at points defining intersections with the same road, but can't find anything to figure that out.
